# Using one YAML definition for the same column as it moves through models

Tags: dbt

I have some model YAML:

```
version: 2

models:
  - name: my_model

    columns:
      - name: foo
        description: My bestest column
```

...If I make other models which inherit from this one, is there any way to refer back to this column definition when documentation is generated, or do I need to copy-paste the column definition for each model in which the column appears?

In other words, is there a way of defining a column only once to make edits and updates easier.

Cheers,

Graham

Answer (score 4):

I think there are two ways to do it.

**1. using macro**

create a file that contains all those reusable descriptions. you could even use params to customize the description.
e.g. doc_library.sql

```
{% macro column_bestest_doc(col_name) %}
   My bestest column {{ col_name }}
{% endmacro %}
```

then use it in `dbt_project.yml`

```
version: 2

models:
  - name: my_model

    columns:
      - name: foo_1
        description: {{column_bestest_doc(foo_1)}}

  - name: my_model_another

    columns:
      - name: foo_2
        description: {{column_bestest_doc(foo_2)}}
```

---

**2. using YAML anchor**

you could do YAML anchors in dbt_project.yml as in any other yml files.

```
version: 2

models:
  - name: my_model

    columns:
      - name: &foo
        description: My bestest column

  - name: my_model_another

    columns:
      - name: *foo
```

ref:
https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/yaml-anchors/
https://medium.com/@kinghuang/docker-compose-anchors-aliases-extensions-a1e4105d70bd

Answer (score 1):

We have been thinking about this problem extensively as well... our current solution is to modify the [generate_model_yaml](https://github.com/fishtown-analytics/dbt-codegen#generate_model_yaml-source) macro:

```sql
{% macro generate_model_yaml(model_name) %}

{% set model_yaml=[] %}
{% set existing_descriptions = fetch_existing_descriptions(model_name) %}

-- # TO DO: pass model to fetch()
-- if column not blank on current model, use description in returned dict
-- otherwise, use global
-- also extract tests on column anywhere in global scope 

{% do model_yaml.append('version: 2') %}
{% do model_yaml.append('') %}
{% do model_yaml.append('models:') %}
{% do model_yaml.append('  - name: ' ~ model_name | lower) %}
{% do model_yaml.append('    description: ""') %}
{% do model_yaml.append('    columns:') %}

{% set relation=ref(model_name) %}
{%- set columns = adapter.get_columns_in_relation(relation) -%}

{% for column in columns %}
    {%- set column = column.name | lower -%}
    {%- set col_description = existing_descriptions.get(column, '') %}
    {% do model_yaml.append('      - name: ' ~ column ) %}
{% do model_yaml.append('        description: "' ~ col_description ~ '"') %}
    {% do model_yaml.append('') %}
{% endfor %}

{% if execute %}

    {% set joined = model_yaml | join ('\n') %}
    {{ log(joined, info=True) }}
    {% do return(joined) %}

{% endif %}

{% endmacro %}
```

And then get the first description found that matches the column, with `fetch_existing_descriptions()`:

```
{% macro fetch_existing_descriptions(current_model) %}

{% set description_dict = {} %}
{% set current_model_dict = {} %}
{% for node in graph.nodes.values() | selectattr("resource_type", "equalto", "model") %}

    {% for col_dict in node.columns.values() %}

        {% if node.name == current_model %}
            -- Add current model description to seperate dict to overwrite with later
            {% set col_description = {col_dict.name: col_dict.description} %}
            {% do current_model_dict.update(col_description) %}

        {% elif description_dict.get(col_dict.name, '') == '' %}

            {% set col_description = {col_dict.name: col_dict.description} %}
            {% do description_dict.update(col_description) %}

        {% endif %}
        
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}

-- Overwrite description_dict with current descriptions
{% do description_dict.update(current_model_dict) %}

{% if var('DEBUG', False) %}
    
    {{ log(tojson(description_dict), info=True) }}

{% else %}

    {{ return(description_dict) }}

{% endif %}

{% endmacro %}
```

Finally, we use a bash script with the path to the model to write/overwrite a yaml file using the modified `generate_model_yaml` above:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Generates documentation for dbt models.

# Usage: 
# Run from within the gold folder.
# Run with no args for all models. Provide optional relative model path to generate docs for just one model:
# Eg. `$ bash ./scripts/generate_docs.sh [./models/path/to_your_model.sql]`


if [[ -n $1 ]]; then # Build array of one model if optional arg provided

    yml="${1%.sql}.yml" # Create model yml filename
    touch "$yml" && rm "$yml" || exit 1 # Ensure filepath works by testing creation
    array=("$yml")

else # Create array of yml

    array=()
    while IFS=  read -r -d $'\0'; do
        if [[ ${REPLY} != *"src"* ]]; then # Only proceed for model yml files (don't contain "src")
            if [[ -n $1 ]]; then
                # Include only the model yml of the optional arg
                if [[ $(basename $yml) == $(basename $REPLY) ]]; then
                    array+=("$REPLY")
                fi
            else
                array+=("$REPLY")
            fi
        fi
    done < <(find "./models/" -name "*.yml" -print0)

fi

# Create copy model yml with prescribed yml containing docs standard.
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    model=$(basename $i | sed -E 's|[.]yml||g')
    generated_yml=$(dbt run-operation generate_model_yaml --args "model_name: $model" | sed '1d')
    echo "$generated_yml" > "${i}_copy" # Create non-yml copy file to allow script to complete
done

# Once all copies are created, replace originals
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    cat "${i}_copy" > $i
    rm "${i}_copy"
done
```